# Elementary Set Theory - Notation Question

Tags: real-analysis

In the following book:

"Problems in Real Analysis" by Charalambos, problems 1.1, chapter 1. (this book can be easily accessed in the pdf form on the internet). Author asks to establish the following claim:

$$\displaystyle{f\Bigl(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i\Bigr)} \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I} f(A_i)$$

I have a notation question. Does the LHS in the above mean that the domain of the function is any $x \in A_i$ where $i \in I$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $A_i$ are subsets of the domain of $f$ and hence so is their union $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$.
And if $S$ is a subset of the domain of $f$, we (somewhat ambiguously) write $f(S)$ for the set $\{\,f(x)\mid x\in S\,\}$.

Comment: where $S = \{x: x \in \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \}$ ?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal $S$ can be any subset of the domain if one wants to introduce the notation $f(S)$. In the problem at hand, the specific $S=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ is used.